# How does tantra work?

Tags: rituals, tantra, nature

I am trying to understand how mantra - yantra - tantra works ? After googling for few days I got a fair understanding that it is the use of sound and mantras have some words combined in such a way that it has positive effects on mind and surrounding etc.

Now, I am trying to understand how tantra works, like for example : how come a person reciting a mantra can cure or damage a person sitting remotely or can cure himself/herself. I also came to knew something of reiki in which I guess similar thing is used, but I want to understand what happens in the background. Any link, brief would be appreciated. What is that method / art ?

Comment: Can u remove the word scientifically?  Because question would be closed as scientific explanation bis not scope of site. But yeah scriptures have talked on how mantras tantras work

Comment: Ok, i will update it

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: http://literature.awgp.org/book/gopaneeya_gayatri_tantra/v1.1